# Android - Downloading percent in Picasso or Glide

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide

I'm using picasso library for my wallpaper app
I want to show the percent of loading image in the Textview.

How can i do that in picasso or glide library?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like neither of these libraries have such feature out of the box. You can, however, provide your own implementation.

One way to do this with Glide using Square's OkHttp is implementing `com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody` like in [this](https://gist.github.com/fbis251/cfa169fd9e1e142e042c) example.

This is not an answet to your questing, but if you're not limited to Picasso or Glide, [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) has simple `ImageLoadingProgressListener`.

Comment: okHttpUrlLoader doesn't exist in okHttp library ... new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(mOkHttpClient);

Comment: I found it in the integration package [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/integration/okhttp/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/integration/okhttp/OkHttpUrlLoader.java), not the OkHttp project itself.
For more informations, please refer to the [Glide integration library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Integration-Libraries).